# The script at 'https://binaries.soliditylang.org/wasm/soljson-v0.8.1+commit.df193b15.js' failed to load

Tags: contract-development

I'm using Remix online and when switching to any version higher than 0.5.1, I get the following error:

> Worker error: Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts'
> on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at
> 'https://binaries.soliditylang.org/wasm/soljson-v0.8.1+commit.df193b15.js'
> failed to load.

When attempting to access the "https://binaries.soliditylang.org/wasm/soljson-v0.8.1+commit.df193b15.js" in a browser, I get a DNS error. It seems the script is not available. Are they perhaps having issues?

I have tried switching to different EVMs but that does not help.

Since this is my first attempt of programming a smart contract, I really am at a loss since I have no experience.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: I am getting the same error right now.

Comment: Same here! It looks like sometimes the Remix breaks for a while.

Answer (score 0):

the network appears to be working now so the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be you choose the wrong compiler version in remix. i solve this problem by close the current programming window,and then find  your xxx.sol file in workspace->contract and right-click the file, click compile from the Pop-ups, and everything goes well,remix automatic match the right compiler version for your xxx.sol file.
my err is like:
Worker error: Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://binaries.soliditylang.org/wasm/soljson-v0.6.12+commit.27d51765.js' failed to load.